# Ploting sqlite data on a graphview where x-axis represents Weekly days

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, graph

I finally got it plotting but the line rendered remains constant throughout the entire graph and am also having issues with x-axis lebaling to represent weekly days.

[This is what i want to achieve..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6aGS.png)

[Results of what i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcS63.png)

how i achieved that...GraphActivity.OnCreate.

```
LineGraphSeries  lineGraphSeries = new LineGraphSeries<>(getChartData());
lineGraphSeries.setDrawDataPoints(true);

db = new DBAdapter(context);
db.openDB();
graphView.getViewport().setMaxY(db.getTotalMiles()*1.5);
db.closeDB();
```

setting the graph.

```
public Datapoint getChartData(){

    db.openDB();
    Cursor cursor_miles = db.getchartdata();
    DataPoint[] dataPoints = new DataPoint[cursor_miles.getCount()];

    for (int i = 0; i<cursor_miles.getCount(); i++) {

        cursor_miles.moveToLast();

        double miles__ = cursor_cash.getDouble(cursor_miles.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_MILES));

        long _time =(new Date(cursor_miles.getLong(cursor_miles.getColumnIndex(Constants.DATE_))).getTime());
        dataPoints[i] = new DataPoint(_time + (i * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000), miles__);

    }

    db.closeDB();
    return dataPoints;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be that you are using `moveToLast` for every iteration rather than traversing the cursor_miles Cursor.

Instead of :-

```
public Datapoint getChartData(){

    db.openDB();
    Cursor cursor_miles = db.getchartdata();
    DataPoint[] dataPoints = new DataPoint[cursor_miles.getCount()];

    for (int i = 0; i<cursor_miles.getCount(); i++) {

     cursor_miles.moveToLast();

        double miles__ = cursor_cash.getDouble(cursor_miles.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_MILES));

        long _time =(new Date(cursor_miles.getLong(cursor_miles.getColumnIndex(Constants.DATE_))).getTime());
        dataPoints[i] = new DataPoint(_time + (i * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000), miles__);

    }

    db.closeDB();
    return dataPoints;
}
```

You could use :-

```
public Datapoint getChartData(){

    db.openDB();
    Cursor cursor_miles = db.getchartdata();
    DataPoint[] dataPoints = new DataPoint[cursor_miles.getCount()];
    while(cursor_miles.moveToNext) {
        double miles__ = cursor_cash.getDouble(cursor_miles.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_MILES));
        long _time =(new Date(cursor_miles.getLong(cursor_miles.getColumnIndex(Constants.DATE_))).getTime());
        dataPoints[cursor_miles.getPosition()] = new DataPoint(_time + (cursor_miles.getPosition() * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000), miles__);   
    }
    cursor_miles.close();
    db.closeDB();
    return dataPoints;
}
```

Comment: It worked, now the the graph plots well, only problem is thats only half the question.  How abt labeling the x-axis to represent each day of the week.

Comment: @M.Dixon I generally deal specifically with SQLite which was obviously the main issue you were facing. My guess is that it's simply a case of doing a little reading to fix the labels. That should actually be a second question as it's quite clear that you should ask "a specific programming problem" [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I'd suggest that you should show some gratitude, rather than dismiss the help that has allowed you to progress as *"not enough"*.